# Why am I getting a mypy error for Optional type when I have early return for when value is None?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I would appreciate some help with an error I'm having with mypy.

My function looks something like:

```
def get_result(
    f1: float,
    l: List[float],
    d: Dict[float, Optional[List[str]]],
    f2: float,
    s: str
) -> Optional[List[str]]:
    if f1 is in l:
        if d[f2] is None:
            return [s]
        else:
            return sorted(d[f2] + [s])
    return d[f2]
```

Yet, mypy gives `error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("None")` and `note: Left operand is of type "Optional[List[str]]"` for the `return sorted(d[f2] + [s])` line even though I have an early return for when the value is None.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Mypy isn't quite smart enough to remember that a specific item of a dictionary has a specific type after an `is None` or `isinstance` check. It can remember such things if you give that item a name directly. In your example:

```
def get_result(
    f1: float,
    l: List[float],
    d: Dict[float, Optional[List[str]]],
    f2: float,
    s: str
) -> Optional[List[str]]:
    # explicitly name the item that we care about
    d_f2 = d[f2]
    if f1 is in l:
        # use the given name directly
        if d_f2 is None:
            return [s]
        else:
            return sorted(d_f2 + [s])
    return d_f2
```